# Only display posts with comments

Tags: posts, comments, query-posts

I would like to query out only posts that have comments. So posts with comment_count = 0 won't show but anything above that will.

This is what i query but it still picks out posts that doesen't have comments. Is there another way?

```
query_posts(array('comment_count' > 0, 'post_type' => 'letters', 'showposts' => 10, 'post_status' => array('publish'), 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1), 'meta_key' => 'letter_show_on_site', 'meta_value' => "yes"));
```

Comment: `'comment_count'` was not meant to filter posts in that manner. It was used by WP_Query only to order posts.

Comment: okay, thank you for the information. Is there any other way to pick out posts with comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem recently and developed a good solution that maintains paging (which some of the answers here do not) and also allows for only targeting certain comment types and comment approved statuses.

```
function has_comments_join( $join, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ($comment_term = $wp_query->get('post_has_comments')) {
        $join .= $wpdb->prepare(" JOIN $wpdb->comments ON (($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID) AND ($wpdb->comments.comment_type = %s) AND ($wpdb->comments.comment_approved = %s)) ", $comment_term['comment_type'], $comment_term['comment_status']);
    }
    return $join;
}

$results = new WP_Query(array(
    ...
    'post_has_comments' => array(
        'comment_type' => 'review',
        'comment_status' => '1'
    )
);
```

This code can easily be refined to support multiple statuses, conditionals on type and status, etc...  I even have a variant I use to do comparisons on comment meta, similar to the meta_query functionality.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

you can use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'letters',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'letter_show_on_site',
    'meta_value' => "yes"
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $the_query->have_posts()){
    while($the_query->have_posts()){
        the_post();
        global $post;

        //show post which have comment_count > 0
        if( 0 < $post->comment_count ){

            the_title();

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the query below(not tested) you will be able to get all the ids of posts that have comments.

```
$postids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT distinct ID FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->comments where comment_post_ID = ID ORDER BY ID");
```