# WP_Query posts with comments only

Tags: wp-query

I need a flexible solution to put out a list of posts with comments.
I'm trying to get this solution to work, but have no luck:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/219216/91757

I'm always getting the normal list, as on front page of the blog. Even `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? Here's my code so far:

```
<?php function has_comments_join( $join, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ($comment_term = $wp_query->get('post_has_comments')) {
        $join .= $wpdb->prepare(" JOIN $wpdb->comments ON (($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID) AND ($wpdb->comments.comment_type = %s) AND ($wpdb->comments.comment_approved = %s)) ", $comment_term['comment_type'], $comment_term['comment_status']);
    }
    return $join;
}

$results = new WP_Query(array(

    'post_type'             => array( 'post' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
    'posts_per_page'        => 8,
    'order'                 => 'dsc',

    'post_has_comments' => array(
        'comment_type' => 'review',
        'comment_status' => '1'
    )
)); ?>  

<?php while ( $results->have_posts() ): $results->the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'archive' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Everything is working now, except pagination:

```
<?php   
function my_has_comments_filter( $where ) {
    $where .= ' AND comment_count > 0 ';
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_has_comments_filter' );
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page'        => 8,         
    'paged'                 => $paged,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
    'order'                 => 'dsc',
) );
// Don't filter future queries.
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_has_comments_filter' ); ?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'archive' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php joints_page_navi(); ?> // Does not work with original WP code too
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'missing' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: wait.. where you put the whole of your code?

Comment: I mean in your theme files, which file?

Comment: Ah okay, sorry. I use JointsWP (https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/JointsWP/) and copied the archive.php for creating a custom category template.

Comment: You should not be running custom queries in place of the main query. They are always troublesome. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query

Comment: @Pieter Goosen Thanks for your input. At the moment I don't really know how to work with `pre_get_posts`, but I'll deal with it when I have time to study the WP Codex page about the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to change the SQL query for a `WP_Query`, you're going to need to use the `posts_join` filter, or in your case, it's easier to go for a simple `posts_where`:

```
function my_has_comments_filter( $where ) {
    $where .= ' AND comment_count > 0 ';
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_has_comments_filter' );
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
) );

// Don't filter future queries.
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_has_comments_filter' );
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. That works! But what's not working is ignore_sticky_post and pagination. I put my new code under the first one above.

Comment: I think it will work if you remove `query_posts`. Also, don't put `remove_filter` into your while loop, put it right at the end of your `WP_Query`. Finally, if you're going to remove `query_posts` you should also remove `wp_reset_query()`, but still use `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Comment: Okay, now I'm a bit confused, because I have no output anymore since I removed the `WP_Query`. I'm afraid, that I'm not really understand the whole thing. Again the new code above.

Comment: `have_posts()` and `the_post()` work on the global `$wp_query` object. Since you have a new local `$query` object you should use `$query->have_posts()` and `$query->the_post()` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and help me learning! Everything is working now, except the pagination. In my code above I'm using a snippet of my template for pagination, but the original wordpress code does not work too. But if you say, that my code is correct now, I can control the length of the list with the WP_Query array parameters too.